# Is there any way to check read, write information for tables generically for RDBMS databases?

Tags: java, jdbc, rdbms

I need to find RDBMS table metadata for an application. I am able to find Column Metadata, table existence using `java.sql.DatabaseMetaData` and row count by executing query on `java.sql.Statement`.

How need to check

- boolean canRead()
- boolean canWrite()

on table.

I found `isReadOnly()` method in `DatabaseMetaData` class. But it

> Retrieves whether this database is in read-only mode.

Is there any way to check these features generically for RDBMS databases at table level?

Comment: I presume you are asking whether there is a way *other than* attempting to read a row, starting a transaction, attempting to write a row, and rolling back the transaction.  Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [getTablePrivileges()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTablePrivileges-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

> Retrieves a description of the access rights for each table available in a catalog. Note that a table privilege applies to one or more columns in the table. It would be wrong to assume that this privilege applies to all columns (this may be true for some systems but is not true for all.)

The column `PRIVILEGE` from the ResultSet will contain the information you are looking for. If I remember correctly you will get one row in the result for each privilege that was granted.

As the JavaDoc for `getTablePrivileges()` suggests, you might need to also check [getColumnPrivileges()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumnPrivileges-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) - but that depends on your use case and the DBMS you expect to support